# how to use the xpath | operator in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to obtain  either a list of images or one image that present in different xpath to fill default scrapy ImagesPipeline `image_urls` of a site like this [(un)security news](http://www.pueblaonline.com.mx/2015/portal/index.php/seguridad/item/40536-robo-de-hidrocarburo-movil-de-balacera-en-acatzingo-fge-pide-intervencion-de-pgr#.V2LyflXhCUk&panel1-1) by using an or xpath operator in the `response.xpath()`

```
relative_urls = response.xpath('''//*[contains(@class, "rondell-container")]//img/@src |
                                   //*[contains(@class, "itemImageBlock")]//img/@src'''
                                   ).extract()
```

The path works correctly with chrome Xpath Helper extension but when scraping it isn't and I get no images in some cases.

I'm taking into account cases where an article doesn't even have an image.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `|` operator that's at issue? Quite often your literal HTML and rendered DOM will differ, so if your scraper isn't going through an actual browser engine you can't trust tests against a browser engine's view to be helpful.

Comment: Also, can you provide more details on how you're using Scrapy? Is it parsing with BeautifulSoup? lxml.html? More details would be helpful to allow the behavior described to be reproduced without needing to guess at configuration.

Comment: (with `lxml.html`, and the link given, I get `['/2015/portal/media/k2/items/cache/8886aae0d67b1e1821ed45e73b68a2a3_L.jpg']` as a result from the XPath in question, which is presumably correct).

Comment: actually I am using it by extending from `CrawlSpider`,  I create some rules to follow just the urls I need and in some cases I add a callback to a method `parse_item` where I parse directly from the response as stated in de documentation like the example shown above. No BeautifulSoup, no lxml. The path that you got is correct

Comment: Scrapy uses either BeautifulSoup or lxml under the hood. As far as I know, those are the only two backend parsers it supports -- so it *has* to be one or the other, even if you don't know which one it is.

Comment: according to http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-does-scrapy-compare-to-beautifulsoup-or-lxml it doesn't. Even though I can use any of them I'm trying to avoid more dependencies.

Comment: *shrug*. Being as `lxml.html` works, and the default selectors mechanism doesn't, looks like an obvious fix to me. And when I did a `pip install scrapy`, it pulled in lxml as a dependency out-of-the-box, so AFAICT it's a dependency already.

Comment: ok, i'll end up doing that if there is no `selectors` fix. Thanks Charles!

Comment: Have you tried using 2x contains with path like contains or contains instead of  |   ?